# What are the possible causes of pettiness?

Tags: social-psychology, developmental-psychology

There is a question about pettiness [Is it possible to quantify 'pettiness' in a personality?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/is-it-possible-to-quantify-pettiness-in-a-personality)

Which gives a good example of how some people can focus on seemingly unimportant issues, when there are more obvious issues that would seem to warrant attention.

What would cause a person to focus, even fixate on small, petty things; for example:

1. a co-worker's tardiness, when the employer's company is facing a takeover and jobs may be lost.
2. the makeup one of the school Mum's was wearing, when there's been a robbery at the school

I am wondering what the possible causes of pettiness may be?

Comment: I might think that the reasons to behave in some way or other lies on every person individually; although we have similar basis. E.g. for the first example, the situation of the company could be an enhancing factor for this psychological bias, because we are programmed to be competitive against our own species members (Because of natural selection), and a worker might think (consciously or not), that his chances to keep the job are better if he is better than others, which may lead to devalue other people or overrate himself at work. Sorry for my English, have a nice day.

Comment: When jobs may be lost, is focus on tardiness a petty argument?

Comment: There is something called the "[bike-shed effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality)" (law of triviality) which argues it is normal "... that members of an organization give disproportionate weight to trivial issues."

Answer (score 3):

There can always be many variables for what causes human behavior, within this answer I will focus on three more obvious or, perhap, likely causes for pettiness within individuals.
This could be one of a variety of causes stemming from the following:

- Schadenfreude
- Obsessive Compulsive Disorder (or related disorders)
- Disorders on the Autistic spectrum

**Schadenfreude:**

In the majority of situations this would be the most likely cause of such pettiness, as it is applicable to a more mainstream type of behavior. The chance to show up a deficit or shortcoming in another, motivated by jealousy of, or a feeling of unease stemming from threat  by, that person..

> We are primed for pettiness, programmed to notice seemingly inconsequential gradations, but for good reason: Being chronically dissatisfied is an effective stimulus to best your more complacent peers. (1)

This could well be the result of schadenfreude (translated to harm-joy), which refers to the pleasure people gain from the misfortunes of someone they perceive to be a high achiever or be envious of. This is based on envy derived from poor self esteem and/or lack of validation of that person's self esteem and a reaction to a perceived threat, from a fellow high-achiever.

The greater the  focus on seemingly petty things, the greater the individual's  psychic conflict or neediness and by this I refer to, the need for validation of self-worth and reaffirming their rank as a human being within a given community.  For such anxiety to cloud judgement to give a, seemingly, inconsequential issue, precedence over what seem to be more important issues. For this individual the need to validate themselves as a person is greater than national, global or even cosmic issues for which this individual has no control over, and which may have no immediate effect on that person's life.

> The present research shows that people with low self-esteem experience more schadenfreude toward the misfortune of a high- achiever than those with high self-esteem and that this relationship is mediated by the self-threat evoked by the high-achiever. Moreover, the indirect relationship between self-esteem and schadenfreude is contingent on an opportunity of self-affirmation. When no self-affirmation opportunity is available, low-self-esteem participants experience a stronger self-threat when confronted with a high-achiever, and this self-threat increases their schadenfreude. (2)

- **Obsessive Compulsive Disorder (OCD)**

Although OCD is usually referring to the compulsive ritualised activities of an individual, as a result of an underlying obsession. If an observer with OCD, witness what may be regarded to most people as petty, but the observed behavior happens to cross into the area of obsession for that person, it could well be that person's attempt to alleviate their own anxiety that is triggered by the perceived aberrant behavior. An example being, observing someone leave the toilet cubicle and restroom without washing their hands.

> Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder, or OCD, is an anxiety disorder and is characterized by recurrent, unwanted thoughts (obsessions) and/or repetitive behaviors (compulsions). Repetitive behaviors such as hand-washing, counting or cleaning are often performed with the hope of preventing obsessive thoughts or making them go away. Performing these so-called "rituals," however, provides only temporary relief, and not performing them markedly increases anxiety

- **Disorders on the Autistic spectrum**

People with disorders that lie on the autistic spectrum, can frequently have preoccupation or obsession with details, that may seem inconsequential to others, or even petty. As with OCD, this perceived pettiness could be an attempt to alleviate the individual's anxiety and to assist in making sense of the world, as this type of individual is frequently inflexible and views the world through a set of structured ideas, that do not easily facilitate or blend with the fluid nature of life and human behavior.

> “Obsessions”, “circumscribed interests”, “special interests”, “routines”, “rituals” , 
>   “preoccupations” are some of the terms used when describing the behaviour of young 
>   children with autism. These behaviours belong to one of the three core areas of 
>   impairment in children with autism. (4)

---

References:

- [Why You Think You'll Never Stack Up](http://www.psychologytoday.com/articles/200508/why-you-think-youll-never-stack) by Carlin Flora, Psychology Today (1)
- Self-Esteem, Self-Affirmation, and Schadenfreude
  Wilco W. van Dijk, Guido M. van Koningsbruggen, Jaap W. Ouwerkerk and Yoka M. Wesseling DOI:  10.1037/a0026331 [PDF](http://www.goallab.nl/publications/documents/2011_Emotion_Van%20Dijk%20et%20al.pdf) (2)
- [Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder (OCD)](http://bbrfoundation.org/ocd)
  Brain and Behavior Research Foundation
- Restricted, repetitive and stereotyped patterns of behaviour, interest and activities
  Dr Avril V Brereton, Monash University  [PDF](http://www.med.monash.edu.au/spppm/research/devpsych/actnow/download/factsheet47.pdf) (4)

Comment: Schadenfreude is an interesting argument

Answer (score 1):

Another general possibility is a personality geared towards perfectionism, which is one of the components of Conscientiousness, one of the Big Five personality traits. Individuals who strive for perfect solutions may focus on trivial components.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness

A similar issue is described as maximizing vs. satisficing: does one take a "good enough" answer, or obsess about diminishing returns? This link explains the concept in psychology.

> https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/science-choice/201506/satisficing-vs-maximizing

Answer (score 0):

Narcissism may be petty by definition. For example, materialism plays to the desire of admiration in Narcissistic Personality Disorder. More generally, I'd associate it with a certain kind of maturity deficit. Such are common in Cluster B personality disorders and not just Narcissistic Personality Disorder:[Notes on Narcissistic Personality Disorder](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/neurosagacity/201702/how-tell-youre-dealing-malignant-narcissist). So, Envy would be one component. Failure to tolerate any criticism. Rash responses, temper tantrums. Keeping up with the Jonses'.

From this I'd expect pettiness to correspond with relatively low Openness to experience, low Agreeableness, High Neuroticism. Most petty people I've known aren't especially Extroverted. Conscientiousness overlaps in Narcissism in odd ways.

Low Openness, and High Neuroticism tends to correspond with Low Fluid Intelligence.

So I'm not sure if pettiness itself can be measured directly, but I think measures of the Big 5 Personality Traits and Fluid Intelligence can be used to indicate this quality.

[Some Notes on Meanness in Narcissism from Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/insight-is-2020/201807/what-makes-some-narcissists-mean-competitive-and-jealous)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Please visit our site [tour]. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be backed up with reliable references so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's/answerer's background. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.